# Telegram-bot: как отправлять ответы пользователю, строго в определённый чат, когда пользователь использует более одного бота с сервера?

Tags: telegram-bot

Ситуация: есть два и более ботов, которые привязаны к одному серверу, но по разным url соответственно, т.е. https://example.com/bot{1..n}

При добавлении ботов узнаём chat_id пользователя, дабы отправлять ему ответы на команды, но возникла проблема: если один пользователь добавит несколько ботов одновременно, то в какой бы бот он не писал, ответ будет приходить в первый добавленный.

Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что в методе отправки ответа использовался токен, созданный для первого бота, а нужно было использовать другой токен для соответствующего бота:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot[TokenBot{1..n}]/sendMessage
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотреть по дате получения сообщения. В своем боте я для удобства подключил БД, которая пишет дату и время, chat_id и т.д.

Comment: Речь о ботах, их больше одного. Они используют chat_id из бд. Только сообщения приходят не в тот чат с ботом, а в самый первый чат с другим ботом.

Comment: @edem ввиду того, что как то более конкретно нельзя идентифицировать, то можно попробовать отдельно писать в БД с каким ботом приходит сообщение.